# How can I have a link to a facebook page open in the FB app on a mobile device and still open in a browser on desktop

Tags: facebook, nativeapplication

How can I have a link to a facebook page open in the FB app on a mobile device and still open in a browser when the fb app is not installed or on a desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to show/hide a link on different screen sizes. Or you could check the window size in javascript and depending on what that is you could change the href to the mobile or desktop site

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries